How to Create an FM Signal with a MHz Carrier Frequency and kHz Sinusoidal Information Signal for PLL in Simulink?
I am working on a project in Simulink that involves a Phase-Locked Loop (PLL). In this project, I need to use two different frequencies—one in the MHz range and the other in the kHz range. I am trying to understand how to correctly combine these frequencies so that they can be effectively used within the PLL system in Simulink.
